# How to place output Jar and War files in another specified folder(it may be outside of the project)?

Tags: maven, spring-boot-actuator

i want to place output jar or war in another separate folder which should contain only jar or war file. i.e folder may be outside of the project. is that possible?

Comment: The question is: Why do you need that? What is the intention of that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although generally it's not a good idea to deviate from Maven conventions, you can use `outputDirectory` [parameter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#outputDirectory) in `maven-jar-plugin` to specify a directory other than `${project.build.directory}`

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>path/to/your/folder</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```